# How to get counts from a table to produce a heatmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, statistics, heat-map

I am trying to create a heat map of doctors per zip code based on zip code. I have a table with the doctors and their zip codes, some of them repeating because there is more than one doctor per zip code. I also have a shapefile with polygon features of zip codes.

I have tried the Get Count tool (which returned the total number of rows) and the Find Duplicate tool, which did nothing for me. Find Duplicate just produced a confusing table with the same amount of records as the original that did not actually have the correct input values in the center column (many were something different) and the counts in the right column did not match the counts I see (via select by attribute: zipcode = thiszipcode, result: x were selected).

My thought is that I could create a table based on the doctors table that lists each unique value (the zipcode) and its count. I would then join that table to the zip code shapefile and create a nice heat map. It seems so simple, but I cannot figure out how to get the count. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: For the record, you're going to end up with a classed (possibly unclassed if each unique value/doctor count gets its own color) choropleth map, not a heatmap. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-to-build-effective-heat-maps for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [summarize](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) the table by zip code.  Choose zip code as Statistics Field and the Statistic Type COUNT.  Then for Case Field choose zip code.  The output table will give you the count of Doctors by zip code.
You can also do this in ArcMap by right clicking on the field you want to summarize and select 'summarize.'

Comment: @tiffany Frequency does more directly what you're after, but Summary Statistics (the link in the answer) doesn't require an Advanced license like Frequency does (obviously not an issue for you, but for the sake of others) and is actually more capable. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102507/summarizing-data-on-arcgis-10-1 Note that Summary Statistics is different from and considerably more capable than [Summarize](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000055000000) - which cannot do case fields.